# Missing required parameter for Route laravel error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Blade.php

```
<tbody>
foreach ($leave as $model)
<tr>
<td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
<td>{{ $model->employee_id }}</td>
<td>{{ $model->name }}</td>
<td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($model->leave_start_date)->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
<td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($model->leave_end_date)->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
<td>{{ $model->leave_type }}</td>
<td>{{ $model->leave_reason }}</td>
<td>{{ $model->is_leave_paid }}</td>
<td><div class="btn-group btn-group-sm"><a href="{{ route('admin.leaveApprove', $model->id) }}"title="Accept" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
<a href="{{ route('admin.leaveReject', $model->employee_id) }}" title="Reject" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></div></td></tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

controller

```
public function LeaveReject($employee_id) {
$leaveApprove = employees_leaves::find($employee_id);
dd($leaveApprove);
$leaveApprove->is_approved = 1;
$leaveApprove->save();
$employeeDetails = EmployeeDetail::where('employee_id', $employee_id)->first();
$employeeDetails->remaining_holiday += 1;
$employeeDetails->save();
session()->flash('error', 'Leave Rejected.');
return redirect()->route('admin.leaveRequests');
}
```

route

`Route::get('/reject/{employee_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\Backend\AdminController::class, 'LeaveReject'])->name('admin.leaveReject');`

error - Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.leaveReject] [URI: admin/reject/{employee_id}] [Missing parameter: employee_id].

Hlo guys the above code is regard leave approve and reject.

what i want is on blade.php  tag {{ route('admin.leaveReject',$model->employee_id) }} so instead of error need to show employee id and on table i have employee_id but still showing error on view.

if i do here $model->id it's working but i need employee_id instead of the default id.

due to this functionality i can approve and reject leave and manage the leave remaining data.

thanks from advance who will help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ID in an associative array, so the route knows which parameter belongs to which ID.

```
 {{ route('admin.leaveReject', ['employee_id' => $model->employee_id]) }}
```

Comment: i have tried this too but still getting same error.